# react, redux can't get the state from the store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, store, dispatch

**Component react**

```
const OperationDisplayMenu = (props) => {
           return( 

                <OperationDisplayMenuAll dataSpending={dataSpending}/>
                <OperationDisplayMenuTooday todayRecords={todayRecords}/>
            )
}


const OperationDisplay = ( {Spends, TodayRecords} ) => 
{
const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(todayRecords());
        dispatch(fetchSpendings());
    }, []);

return(

 <OperationDisplayMenu dataSpending={Spends}  todayRecords={TodayRecords}/>
)
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {

    return {
        Spends: state.data.fetchedSpendings,
        TodayRecords: state.data.todayRecords
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(OperationDisplay)
```

- 

From store to component i want to get state from ajax request.
Spends state I am getting correctly

But the TodayRecords state, at the beginning is loaded empty, then loaded correctly. But in the component it remains empty.
*

**action.js**

```
action.js


export function todayRecords(){
    return async dispatch => {

        const userData = await userDataGetter();
        const userID = userData.userId;

        const date = new Date();
        const DayEnd = date.getDate();
        const YearEnd = date.getFullYear();
        const MonthEnd = date.getMonth();

        const DateStart = new Date(YearEnd, MonthEnd, DayEnd );
        const DateEnd = new Date(YearEnd, MonthEnd, DayEnd + 2);

        try{
            const responseSpends = await axios.post('/api/getRecordSpends/toDate', {userID, DateStart, DateEnd})
            const responseEarns = await axios.post('/api/getRecordEarns/toDate' , {userID, DateStart, DateEnd})
            
            await Array.prototype.push.apply(responseSpends.data,responseEarns.data); 

            const sortArr = await selectionSortDate(responseSpends.data);

            console.log("sortArr", sortArr);
            dispatch( {type: SET_TODAY_RECORDS, payload: sortArr});

        }catch(e){
            console.log(`Axios request failed in getRecordSpend/toDate: ${e}`);
        }

    }
}

**reducer.js**
```

import {SET_TODAY_RECORDS} from './types'

const initialState = {

```
todayRecords: []
```

}

export const dataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

case SET_TODAY_RECORDS:

```
        return { ...state, todayRecords: action.payload }
```

}

```
The screenshot shows that at the beginning I receive an empty state from the store, then it comes full.
https://ibb.co/cCR7B4d
```

Comment: Are you returning state when no case is matching in the reducer? What actions are dispatched and what changes do they make to the state (check redux devtools)?

Comment: https://ibb.co/rxJyfcd 

Yes, it comes, but at first it comes empty, for this reason I cannot render the state in the component. Check screen

Comment: https://ibb.co/cCR7B4d   

Here you can see that it first comes empty.

Comment: Initially the data is empty, then the component renders, then the action is dispatched which will set the data **later** and causes the component to render again. I don't see the problem here. Maybe add a loading value in the thunk action.

Comment: The point is that I receive other data immediately. And then in this case, empty data first appears in the component, and then the data is reloaded, the component does not re-render it, and the problem is that I cannot render this data in the component.